# ArcGIS 10.2 Calculate xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop

In ArcGIS 10.2, I would like to know how can I calculate xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax coordinates in a polygon features?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] the question to specify if you want the extent of individual features or of the overall feature class,  and if this needs to be in Python, what code you have written so far.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the steps for individual features within a feature class:

1. Add feature class to ArcMap
2. Open attribute table and add four Double fields (xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax)
3. Right click on each field name and select Field Calculator and select the Python parser at the top
4. Run the following python statement for each related field/calculation

   !shape.extent.XMin!

   !shape.extent.XMax!

   !shape.extent.YMin!

   !shape.extent.YMax!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Minimum Bounding Geometry](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003q000000) tool to creat a rectangle enclosing each polygon feature.

Then run [Add Geometry Attributes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Add_Geometry_Attributes/001700000191000000/) to add the minimum and maximum X and Y coordinates of each rectangle as fields to the attribute table (choose the `EXTENT` geometry property).

If necessary, you can join these 4 extent fields to the original feature class using [Join Field](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Join_Field/001700000065000000/).